# In SQL Server 2008, what default date should I use if I don't want it to be null?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have columns that are of datetype, that I use for things like created, lastmodified etc.

I don't want these columns to allow for nulls, is there a best practise in terms of what I should use for their unused, initialized state?

e.g. should I use whatever value datetime.minvalue is?

Answer (score 10):

You should use NULL - this is what it is for; unknown or uninitialized values.

As mentioned in the comments there is no point for making `DateCreated` nullable. Some people even argue that a good and highly normalized database design should not allow null values at all - see for example this [article](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/null-values-in-a-database.html) - and I tend to agree.

Comment: Why would you use NULL for CreatedDate? I would have thought that if a record exists then it must therefore have been created and hence should have a CreatedDate?

Comment: Sansom, its a contextual matter; whats best value to put in LastModified column?

Comment: If the record hasn't been modified, NULL is the best value to put in a LastModified column.

Comment: One could consider the creation as a special case of modification and initialize creation and modification date with the same value. (I don't want to argue that this is better or worse then starting with null - it's just another option.)

Comment: Using nullable column can be justified in real world - imaging you are maintaining the "Big Ball of Mud", and feel the need of tracking creation time in a table, which was not part of the original schema. You may have to use either nullable column or default value, to maintain the best compatibility with all the existing apps.

Answer (score 5):

My preference is to set a default value of getDate() or getUTCDate() for columns in such circumstances.

For example, CreatedDate should not be NULL otherwise the record should theoretically not exist in the first place?

Subsequently if a record exists then it has been created and the therefore has also been modified and so modified date could also have a default value of getDate().

This is also the approach that is typically used to track record/row changes in a Data Warehouse.

Comment: Creation <> modification in most cases. Creation is the addition of a new row of data; modification typically alters the originally created row.

Comment: Also, unless your application is tied to a given locale and will never be used elsewhere, it is almost always better to use `GetUtcDate()` than `GetDate()`.  As soon as you start dealing with more than one timezone, storing dates in anybody's local time becomes a very bad idea.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: An important point that is certainly worth a mention!

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: +1.  But even if you only have one timezone, if you have daylight saving time then storing dates in local time is a very bad idea.  You can't easily compute deltas across the clock changes, and if any activity occurs the night the clocks go backwards then you may have ambiguous timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use NULL when you want to store an unused date.  When you are reading it out you can check for NULL and use DateTime.MinValue if you want.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want these columns to allow for nulls, is there a best-practise in terms of what I should use for their unused, initialized state?

Since you don't want to use `null`, you could use January 1, 1753 0:00:00. This is the minimum possible value for a `datetime` in SQL Server and unlikely to be an actual value in your data set.

But really, you should use `null` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime.MinValue does not fit inside the datetime data type. You could use the datetime2 data type, but like other recommended, you should use NULL.

I frequently create a column like LastModified or LastLogin and it does default to null.

Seeing a null quickly inform me that the user never modified the data or logged into the system. The NULL value in this case does mean something.

Answer (score 1):

If your columns really are `Created` and `LastModified`, then why not just initialize them using `GetDate()` (or better, `GetUtcDate()`)?  That's how filesystems initialize the datetime stamps of newly created files.

But, as others have pointed out, there is no reason to be afraid of `null`.  If you really mean "has no applicable value", then it seems `null` is a perfectly good way of expressing that.

Answer (score 1):

The unused, uninitialized state is exactly what NULL is designed to represent. You should allow NULL where it's appropriate (eg., in the TERMINATIONDATE column if something hasn't been terminated), and use proper values where NULL isn't (like for DATECREATED when a row is added).

Using nonsense values for NULL dates is confusing to users. "How can the terminated date be in 2099? We're not IN 2099 yet!", or "How can the termination date be in 1732? We didn't exist then!"

Uninitialized means exactly that - uninitialized. It doesn't mean "initialized, but with a bogus value".

Comment: Even better when your app is still in use in 2099, and suddenly every employee has been terminated!  You're building up a nice lot of work for the Y2.099K bugfixers

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with the `NULL/GETDATE()` answers.

As a general best practice, I would avoid storing special datetime values anywhere unless you are prepared to wrap them regularly.  Because you end up with having to fix logic to add thresholds when `DATEDIFF`s start to come out with thousands of months difference, etc.

The rule I go with for dates is never a special datetime value and `NOT NULL` (by constraint/table definition) unless there is a **need** for a special reserved date value, then I try to use `NULL`.  If I need multiple reserved dates, I look at individual flag columns with `NULL` for the datetime instead or joining to a date dimension instead of a datetime column (particularly in warehousing).

In your case with `DateCreated` and `DateModified`, I initialize both to `GETDATE()` with column defaults.  `DateModified` typically gets refreshed in the `UPDATE` trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put a default date in that was anything except the date the record was entered (and then only if it made sense to do so as in a date_created field). For instance if you use a data not likely to be used in the other data, in the first place, it is incorrect data and that will come back to haunt you someday. Someone who doesn't know that you did such a silly thing will someday be looking for the incomplete records and will of course not find any because there is a date. Or suppose you want the records between a cetain begin and end date and records where the process had begun but not ended. It is harder to query this with a fake date inthere than with a null. Suppose you want the records that are ealier than a set date, you will then have to remember to exclude these records or they will show up in your recordsset, same if you want the later records if you use a date like 3000/01/01. So this is just as much work as rememebering to deal with null might be in querying the database only you are far, far less likely to do so. Therefore you will more frequently have wrong results to date-centered queries.

Null is for precisely these situations where you don't know what the value should be at the time of data entry. Never fake up data to avoid using null. It is a very poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

If best practice is really what you are after, use NULL...  end of discussion.  Any other choice is what we call less-than-best practice.  As usual, there are lots of less-than-best practices to choose from.  Lots of them mentioned here!

Answer (score 0):

Null doesn't necessarily work that well for indexing or queries (like between). I tend to use 01/01/0001 or 12/31/9999 in places that beg for a comparable date. (datetime2)

Comment: In what way does NULL not work? It works fine in indexes (NULL rows typically come first, then rows with actual dates), and works perfectly with BETWEEN (NULL rows never match the condition, which is correct).

Comment: Yes, with DATETIME2, that might work - but for DATETIME, a date of "01/01/0001" won't be much fun :-(